# My query text is not recognized when building a RAG + langchain project

Tags: python, arguments, openai-api, langchain, chromadb

I'm following this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tcqEUSNCn8I) made by Pixegami to create a rag for construction rules that apply to Swedish architects. And I am a beginner, so the problem might be simple and not related to the specific task of building a RAG.

Here's "my" code:

```
import argparse
from dataclasses import dataclass
from langchain.vectorstores.chroma import Chroma
from langchain_openai import OpenAIEmbeddings
from langchain_community.chat_models import ChatOpenAI
from langchain.prompts import ChatPromptTemplate

CHROMA_PATH = "chroma"

PROMPT_TEMPLATE = """
Answer the question based only on the following context:

{context}

---

Answer the question based on the above context: {question}
"""


def main():
    # Create CLI.
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("query_text", type=str, help="is the word regler used in this text?")
    args = parser.parse_args()
    query_text = args.query_text

    # Prepare the DB.
    embedding_function = OpenAIEmbeddings()
    db = Chroma(persist_directory=CHROMA_PATH, embedding_function=embedding_function)

    # Search the DB.
    results = db.similarity_search_with_relevance_scores(query_text, k=3)
    if len(results) == 0 or results[0][1] < 0.7:
        print(f"Unable to find matching results.")
        return

    context_text = "\n\n---\n\n".join([doc.page_content for doc, _score in results])
    prompt_template = ChatPromptTemplate.from_template(PROMPT_TEMPLATE)
    prompt = prompt_template.format(context=context_text, question=query_text)
    print(prompt)

    model = ChatOpenAI()
    response_text = model.predict(prompt)

    sources = [doc.metadata.get("source", None) for doc, _score in results]
    formatted_response = f"Response: {response_text}\nSources: {sources}"
    print(formatted_response)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

When I run the code I get the following error message:

```
usage: query_data.py [-h] query_text
query_data.py: error: the following arguments are required: query_text
```

At first I asked ChatGPT what could be wrong and got the answer that non-English characters might not be allowed, so now I have tried altering the query with English characters only, but I still don't get it to work. I thought that I maybe didn't have the `argsparse` so I installed it via `pip install argparse`.

I can see that the code in Pixegami's editor is coloured differently than mine. `"query_text = args"` is light blue in my editor and the rest is white but in his editor the whole line is white.

This is where I'm stuck and I'd be happy to provide additional information if needed.

Comment: The code tells you what's wrong. You are supposed to be calling it with an argument, like `python querydata.py something` where probably you can guess better than me what `something` should be; but maybe try `python querydata.py "is the word 'regler' used in the text?"`

Comment: `argparse` is part of the standard library so you have probably created a mess or at least confusion for yourself. If you have used a virtual environment, just scrap it and start over. If not, probably learn to use virtual environments before you make further modifications to your system.

Comment: The `help` string for `querystring` is not helpful. I guess it's an example of what you could put there, rather than a description; it definitely should be the latter.

Comment: The stuff about non-English characters not working is probably complete bogus. A few Scandinavian characters should work fine, I would imagine (though there might be issues with some Asian writing systems).

Comment: As such, the question is unrelated to anything in the code; you simply were trying to use it incorrectly. I'm voting to close as typo / no repro.